# How do I handle Palindrome with spaces in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, palindrome, deque

I'm trying to check if a string is palindrome in python using deque. But the code below just checks a string with no space, how can I adjust it to a code which handles strings with spaces as well? e.g: It only works if I write the input as  "BORROWORROB" but not when it's "BORROW OR ROB"

```
from pythonds.basic import Deque
def isPalindrome(word):
    if word is None:
        return False
    if len(word) <= 1:
       return True

    DQ = Deque()
    for w in word:
        DQ.addRear(w)

    while (DQ.size() > 1):
        front = DQ.removeFront()
        rear = DQ.removeRear()
        if front != rear:
            return False
    return True


def readInput():
    inp = input("Enter string: ")
    return inp

word = readInput()
print ("Is \"{}\" a palindrome: {}".format(word, isPalindrome(word)))
```

Comment: Do you mean that the code should ignore any spaces in the input?

Comment: yes exactly, I've edited my question again clarifying this matter. @mkrieger1

Comment: Are you looking for an answer explaining how to use python string methods to remove spaces for you, or are you looking for an answer explaining how to process a string manually by iterating over its characters? With python string methods, `s.replace(' ', '')` or `''.join(s.split())` will remove the spaces from a string `s`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's solved later @Stef

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to remove white spaces before starting the logic of the function:

```
from pythonds.basic import Deque
def isPalindrome(word):
    word = word.replace(" ", "")
    if word is None:
        return False
    if len(word) <= 1:
       return True

    DQ = Deque()
    for w in word:
        DQ.addRear(w)

    while (DQ.size() > 1):
        front = DQ.removeFront()
        rear = DQ.removeRear()
        if front != rear:
            return False
    return True


def readInput():
    inp = input("Enter string: ")
    return inp

word = readInput()
print ("Is \"{}\" a palindrome: {}".format(word, isPalindrome(word)))
```

Comment: Alternatively, skip adding it: `for w in word: if w != ' ': DQ.addRear(w)`.